# Query Parent and Children from single table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have a single table that hosts all of my users. Now some users have `team_leaders` which reference the user id of the team leader which is also stored in the database.

Now, what I wanted to do do (and can't figure out) is how to query the database where it retrieves a list of the ids of all the team members and the leader in one result set.

For Example

```
name | id | team_leader
--------------------------------------------------
Jack | 1  | null
--------------------------------------------------
Susan| 2  | 1
--------------------------------------------------
Bob  | 3  | 1
--------------------------------------------------
Eric | 4  | null
--------------------------------------------------
```

`SELECT name FROM users where team_leader = '<some user's id>'`

returns `[ 'Susan', Bob']`

But I would like it to return the team leader included, such as

`['Jack', 'Susan', 'Bob']`

Does anyone have any idea how to include the team leader in the query results?

EDIT:

Okay, so it seems like I have not explained myself 100%, my apologies. so the goal of this query is to do as follows.

I have another table called `leads` and there is a field there that is called `user_id` which correlates to the user that has access to the lead. Now, I want to introduce the ability for team leaders to update the leads that are associated with their accounts, so if the current user is a team leader they should have the ability to update the `user_id` from their id to anyone on their team, from one of their children to another, and from one of the children to themselves, but not to anyone not on their team. So the way I thought of it was to have a WHERE EXISTS or a WHERE IN (this would mean adding a field to the lead table called `leader_id`) and it checks if the new user_id is in a list of that team leader's members, including themselves.

Based off the example above.

```
UPDATE lead SET user_id = xxx 
WHERE lead.id = yyy
AND ... 
-- here is where I would check that the user_id xxx is part of the current         
-- user's team which must be a team leader, for example user.id = 1
```

So my thought process was to get the previous query to then check against.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: thanks for editing it, didn't know how to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can just use `or`:

```
select name
from users
where team_leader = 1 or id = 1
```

Comment: well if I wanted to test if a user is within that list, such as a `where in` clause, it would always return true which defeats the purpose of it.

Comment: @user2899810 -- having a hard time understanding your comment.  do you have a list of user ids instead of just a single one?  could you perhaps edit your question and show what you are referring to?  and no problem for the edit!

Comment: I agree with sgeddes on this one unless you have grandchildren a simple or statement should do the trick.  If you have a leader of a leader then a more complicated statement would need to be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT name,id,team_leader FROM [users]
    WHERE team_leader=1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT u.name,u.id,u.team_leader from [users] u
  JOIN CTE ON CTE.empno=u.team_leader`enter code here`
  and u.team_leader=1
  )
SELECT * FROM CTE
```